# Assigning individual permissions to custom 'document types' for different user groups

Tags: permissions, groups, document-set

I'm trying to implement this in my work SharePoint site, which is used to store project documents (Word documents, Excel spreadsheets, Powerpoint presentations, Outlook emails). There are new projects that come up regularly, so new documents will be uploaded to the site regularly.

There are different document types, including:

1. Bill of Material
2. Effort estimate
3. Offer document
4. Price sheet
5. Project schedule

There are a number of groups who would have different access levels for different document types, including:

- Engineering team
- Sales team
- Project management (PM) team

So for example, say I want to implement the following group permission levels for each of the document types:

1. Bill of Material

   - Full control: Sales team, Engineering team
   - Read: PM team
2. Effort estimate

   - Full control: Engineering team
   - Contribute: PM team
   - Read: Sales team
3. Offer document

   - Full control: Sales team, Engineering team
   - Read: PM team
4. Price sheet

   - Full control: Sales team
   - No access (hidden): Engineering team, PM team
5. Project schedule

   - Full control: PM team
   - Contribute: Engineering team, Sales team

We used to use a new folder for each project which contained sub-folders for each of the different document types, so that we can control/restrict access for each group by changing the folder permission. We want to move away from using folders and use metadata instead - however, we need to retain the different permission levels for different groups.

What I want to happen is for the document creator to specify the 'document type' as a mandatory field at the start during the document upload/check-in process. Since each document type already has the permission levels for each group pre-defined, that there is no need to manually set them for each document.

My question is, is the above actually possible to implement in SharePoint?

We are currently using SharePoint 2013 (I think), as part of the work Office 365 suite. I also have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed, although I haven't had much experience using this program.

Any guidance/advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using `custom WebPart`.
In WebPart, add file uploader and Document type dropdown.

There are steps to do logic in WebPart

1. Upload document in SharePoint library
2. Break permission of uploaded document in SharePoint library
3. Assign permissions which you mentioned above.

Not necessary to create folder in SharePoint library if not in use